# How to create in Sage system of equations using elements from boolean field

Tags: equation, sage

I want to create a field on 8 elements, and then, using this elements make a System of equations like:

```
nb = 8
varl = [c+ str(p) for c in 'xy' for p in range (nb)]
B = BooleanPolynomialRing(names = varl)

f1 = x1 + x7*x2

f2 = x4*x6*x8 + x7
```

and then....

But in this case Sage give me an error 
NameError: name 'x1' is not defined

And in this case:

```
f1 = x[3] + x[1]*x[2]
f2 = x[4]*x[6]*x[2] + x[7]
```

error:
TypeError: 'sage.symbolic.expression.Expression' object does not support indexing

Answer (score 0):

Once `B` is defined as in the question, its variables have a "display name"
but no "call name", i.e. they display as `x0`, `x2`, ..., `x7`
and `y1`, `y2`, ..., `y7`, but we have not told Sage we would
also like to be able to call them by typing `x0`, `x2`, ..., `x7`
and `y1`, `y2`, ..., `y7`.

One way to make this possible is to run:

```
sage: B.inject_variables()
```

after which we can run the following with no error:

```
sage: f1 = x1 + x7*x2
```

Beware for `f2` though: the code in the question defines
`x0` to `x7` but no `x8`.